# Kubernetes logs from kubectl logs command is different to /var/log/containers in GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, logging, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a GKE cluster on GCP.

Kubernetes logs from kubectl logs command is different to /var/log/containers

kubectl

```
{"method":"GET","path":"/healthz","format":"*/*","controller":"Public::PublicPagesController","action":"healthz","status":204,"duration":0.39,"view":0.0,"request_id":"ca29b519-d1e8-49a2-95ae-e5f23b60c36f","params":{},"custom":null,"request_time":"2022-04-27T15:25:43.780+00:00","process_id":6,"@version":"vcam-backend-vvcam-72_shareholder_event-rc16","@timestamp":"2022-04-27T15:25:43.780Z","message":"[204] GET /healthz (Public::PublicPagesController#healthz)"}
```

And logs in /var/log/containers, something add timestamp into the beginning of my container logs:

```
2022-04-27T15:25:43.780523421Z stdout F {"method":"GET","path":"/healthz","format":"*/*","controller":"Public::PublicPagesController","action":"healthz","status":204,"duration":0.39,"view":0.0,"request_id":"ca29b519-d1e8-49a2-95ae-e5f23b60c36f","params":{},"custom":null,"request_time":"2022-04-27T15:25:43.780+00:00","process_id":6,"@version":"vcam-backend-vvcam-72_shareholder_event-rc16","@timestamp":"2022-04-27T15:25:43.780Z","message":"[204] GET /healthz (Public::PublicPagesController#healthz)"}
```

I want my application log will be consistent, I want it in json format like logs from kubectl command, so I can parse and analyze more.

I want to remove this part: `2022-04-27T15:25:43.780523421Z stdout F`

Does anybody meet this problem? How can I make containers logs same as kubectl command logs?

GKE Version:

```
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.10-gke.2000", GitCommit:"0823380786b063c3f71d5e7c76826a972e30550d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-03-17T09:22:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.14b7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Docker daemon.json

```
{
  "pidfile": "/var/run/docker.pid",
  "iptables": false,
  "ip-masq": false,
  "log-level": "warn",
  "bip": "169.254.123.1/24",
  "mtu": 1460,
  "storage-driver": "overlay2",
  "live-restore": true,
  "log-driver": "json-file",
  "log-opts": {
      "max-size": "10m",
      "max-file": "5"
    }
}
```

Notes: I notice that the timestamp in the beginning of log line only show when we add option `docker logs -t`, [docs here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)
But I still do not know how to fix this problem in GKE cluster.

Comment: I have try kubectl version 1.20 1.21 and 1.22, the problem is still there

Comment: GKE set up default, do not change anything, the problem is still there

Comment: I do not meet this problem on AWS EKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is related to Container Runtime Interface (CRI). You can read about CRI [here](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/12/container-runtime-interface-cri-in-kubernetes/).

For now, I'm still can not change the log format as I want, I just adapt to this new format. This format is called `CRI log format`, the CRI default of GKE cluster always produce log in this format, and aggregation log applications adapt to this new CRI log format too:

- This is PR of `Grafana/Loki` to support CRI log format: [PR](https://github.com/grafana/loki/pull/365)
- Fluent-bit create a new parser for CRI log format: [Docs](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/v/1.8/installation/kubernetes#container-runtime-interface-cri-parser)

So I think you need to change the way you approach this problem: If we can not change the log format as we want, we can use application support this log format.

Notes: I'm not sure but I think this problem come from: `Kubernetes is removing support for Docker as a container runtime` - [docs](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/) , and the new container runtime produce this CRI log format.